# Validation for list of Enum in request body which is still list if fields

Tags: c#, .net, enums, fluentvalidation

I set up the list of fields which are need to be passed as a request body for Web API . FluentValidation has been used for validation. I am getting right response and validations for the others fields but when it comes to validation for List of Enum, is not working properly. Could you please give me hand to figure it out? (My assumption is it is not possible to validate list of enum which is part of list). these are some part of code: (As you can see I can send this request for "actions" which is not correct. It is supplied 2 of actions as a single string) it is working fine for the others two but not for "actions")

Thanks :-)

```
 public enum properAction
    {
        [Description("I")]
        Insert = 0,

        [Description("U")]
        Update = 1,

        [Description("D")]
        Delete = 2
    }
```

```
  {

       public List<string> FirstNames { get; set; }


       public List<string> positions { get; set; }


       public List<properAction?> Actions { get; set; }
   }
```

valdtions:

```
    //first name
        RuleForEach(x => x.SearchAuditsRequest.FirstNames).StringLengthRangeValidation(1, 10);
        // postiton
        RuleForEach(x => x.SearchAuditsRequest.positions).StringLengthRangeValidation(1, 10);
        // Action
        RuleForEach(x => x.SearchRequestBody.Actions).IsInEnum();
```

PostMan :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When deserialising enums in a request, a string containing multiple valid enum values is interpreted as a sequence of bit flags, which will be combined using the bitwise AND-operator.

This means that "insert, update" will translate to `0b0 & 0b1` (binary 0 and binary 1), which is `0b1`, which is the `Update` enum value again, which is indeed valid.

To make sure combinations like these do not overlap into another valid enum value, use non-zero multiples of 2, as follows:

```cs
public enum properAction
{
    Insert = 1,
    Update = 2,
    Delete = 4
}
```

In binary, these values are all strings of zeroes with a single `1`, meaning that a combination of multiple values will have multiple `1`s, which will never be a valid value.